# How do I set a visible property of a div element to true or false in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I would like to be able to do this:

```
$(".panel").visible = true;
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 87):

For the `display` CSS property, use [`.show()`, `.hide()` or `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/basics/) to affect whether it displays, like this:

```
$(".panel").show();
//or to hide:
$(".panel").hide();
//toggle show/hide
$(".panel").toggle();
//or show/hide based on boolean:
$(".panel").toggle(bool);
```

For the `visibility` CSS property, you need to set it manually (jQuery is mostly built around `display`), using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like this:

```
$(".panel").css("visibility", "visible");
//or:
$(".panel").css({ visibility: "visible"});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a css property i am using vb.net

Comment: @bill - In that case you *can't* show it from jQuery, since it's not even in the page the client has no knowledge of it.  Instead of `Visible="false"` in the server tag, you need `style="display: none;"`  so it still renders in the page.  To be a bit clearer, it's not a `<div>` property, it's an ASP.Net control property that controls rendering.

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked:

```
document.getElementById('my_elementid').style.visibility='visible';
```

Comment: he asked for jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can by using ClientScript
on serverside call your jquery method

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hideslidertab", "hideslidertab();", true);
```